# Know When a Synced Realm is Up to Date

Tags: swift, realm

Is there a way to know when a local Realm is done syncing with the Realm on a server? Or, to know if the local Realm is up to date with the server Realm?

I have a bug because an operation is being performed when iOS app is first opened. This operation is being performed on stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the shipping build, at present. However, we're working on a PR to add that functionality right now: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4535

It should be ready to go very soon. :)